# TextFormField not appearing in Simulator

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been trying to make the TextFormField ('email:') appear in my Simulator, but it's not appearing in my Simulator as following:

[image]

However when I make changes to any other things, it does change, so the Simulator is not a problem.

This is my login_page.dart file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget{
  @override  
  State createState() => new LoginPageState();
}

class LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage>{
  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: new Text("SMART ID", textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Open Sans', fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        leading: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Image.asset(
            "assets/arrowPNG.png",
            scale: 8.0,
          )
        )
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage('assets/background.png'),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.30,
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image.asset('assets/arrowPNG.png', scale: 2.5),
                  SizedBox(height: 20,),
                  Text("SMARTID", style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 30, color: Colors.black, fontFamily: 'Open Sans', fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,       
                  ),
                  ),
                  Text("Attendance & Wallet Monitoring", style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black, fontFamily: 'Open Sans', fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                  )
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.85,
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("Version 1.0", style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black, fontFamily: 'Open Sans', fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                  )
                  )
                ],
              )
            )
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LoginForm extends StatefulWidget{
  @override 
  LoginFormState createState(){
    return LoginFormState();
  }
}

class LoginFormState extends State<LoginForm>{
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String _username, _password;

  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    body: Card(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Form(
          key: formKey,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Username:'
                ),
                validator: (input) => !input.contains('0') ? 'Username cannot be blank' : null,
                onSaved: (input) => _username = input,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How do I resolve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, Simulator is not a problem. The problem is in your code. You have correctly created the LoginPage. To correct the LoginForm widget, in your LoingFormState's build function replace:

```
body: Card(
    // your usual code that you have above
)
```

with

```
return Card(
// your usual code that you have above
)
```

Also you have not used the LoginForm Widget in the LoginPage, and that is the reason the form is not visible. Simply, creating a widget doesn't include the widget on any screen, you have to use the widget.

You can do that by adding the widget inside the body section of LoginPageState's build function. To use the widget type

```
body: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
           // your other widgets
           LoginForm(),
    ]
)
```

like you do for any other widget.

This should solve your problem

Comment: It says my 'Card' is a dead code after changing it to return Card()

Comment: Did you put simply Card() without the code you have inside the card widget? 
You should retain the code inside Card() widget. Only replace 'body: ' with 'return'.
If you still have issue, please paste the error and the updated code.